# awk grouping and spliting multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to split a line on multiple delimiters and group the output into individual elements that I can reorder. I'm on a BSD system running the pkg_info command. The output looks like this.

```
yaesu-0.13nb1       Control interface for Yaesu FT-890 HF transceiver   
skk-jisyo-cdb-201212 Dictionary collection for SKK  
dbskkd-cdb-2.00nb1  SKK dictionary server based on cdb
libchewing-0.2.7    The intelligent phonetic input method library  
skk-jisyo-201212    Dictionary collection for SKK  
autoconf-2.69nb2    Generates automatic source code configuration scripts  
pkg-config-0.28     System for managing library compile/link flags 
python27-2.7.5      Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
```

The package name always contains letters and numbers the version is the last entry attached to the name and the description is always separated by at least one white space. The most complex example is, "skk-jisyo-cdb" is the package name. "201212" is the version and "Dictionary collection for SKK" is the description.

I need to separate the version from the package name, leaving the package name intact with the "-" left in it while splitting the version info from there and making that an element of its own. Lastly I need to have the description remain in tact as a third element.

I think either awk or sed is capable of doing this but have yet to be able to group the elements correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

Here are a few of the thing I have tried so far:

```
pkg_info -a | awk -F'[[:space:]]*' '{print $1}' | awk -F- '{$NF=" "$NF;sub(/ /,"-")}1'
```

output:

```
yaesu- 0.13nb1
skk-jisyo cdb  201212
dbskkd-cdb  2.00nb1
libchewing- 0.2.7
skk-jisyo  201212
autoconf- 2.69nb2
pkg-config  0.28
python27- 2.7.5
```

And

```
pkg_info -a | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-| ";OFS="\t"}{print $1$2}'
```

output:

```
yaesu0.13nb1
skkjisyo
dbskkdcdb
libchewing0.2.7
skkjisyo
autoconf2.69nb2
pkgconfig
python272.7.5
```

I have been able to separate out the package name and version using 2 commands but this is not what I want/need. These are just for reference. 
This will get me the version by itself:

```
pkg_info -a | awk -F'[[:space:]]*' '{print $1}' | awk -F- '{print $NF }'
```

This will get me the package name by itself:

```
pkg_info -a | awk -F'[[:space:]]*' '{print $1}' | sed 's/\(.*\)\(-.*\)/\1/g'
```

What I need my final output to be is `$pkgname\t$version\t$description\n` this would be seperated by a `\t` Tab
With the most complex example the output would be:
`skk-jisyo-cdb\t201212\tDictionary collection for SKK\n`

Comment: @Ed Morton, I added a bit more clarification

Comment: Sorry Ed, I jumped the gun and didn't give you what you were looking for again. I just modified it again. I think with the example you gave me I can make it work. I'll give them a try now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide enough detail to be sure but this MAY be what you want:

```
$ sed -r 's/([^[:blank:]]+)-([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+/\1\t\2\t/' file
yaesu   0.13nb1 Control interface for Yaesu FT-890 HF transceiver   
skk-jisyo-cdb   201212  Dictionary collection for SKK  
dbskkd-cdb      2.00nb1 SKK dictionary server based on cdb
libchewing      0.2.7   The intelligent phonetic input method library  
skk-jisyo       201212  Dictionary collection for SKK  
autoconf        2.69nb2 Generates automatic source code configuration scripts  
pkg-config      0.28    System for managing library compile/link flags 
python27        2.7.5   Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
```

.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{ pkg=ver=$1; sub(/-[^-]+$/,"",pkg); sub(/.*-/,"",ver); sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); print pkg, ver, $0}' file  
yaesu   0.13nb1 Control interface for Yaesu FT-890 HF transceiver   
skk-jisyo-cdb   201212  Dictionary collection for SKK  
dbskkd-cdb      2.00nb1 SKK dictionary server based on cdb
libchewing      0.2.7   The intelligent phonetic input method library  
skk-jisyo       201212  Dictionary collection for SKK  
autoconf        2.69nb2 Generates automatic source code configuration scripts  
pkg-config      0.28    System for managing library compile/link flags 
python27        2.7.5   Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
```

Change the separator from `tab` to whatever it is you want.

Comment: This works for what I need! Thanks @Ed Morton! I just needed to change the OFS to OFS='\\t'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default field separator and the split function on field 1. Then you only need to append the field separator and the last item of the split to the first field:

```
awk '{n=split($1, a, "-"); $1=$1 FS a[n]}1'
```

Comment: This gives me an output of: `yaesu-0.13nb1 0.13nb1 Control interface for Yaesu FT-890 HF transceiver
skk-jisyo-cdb-201212 201212 Dictionary collection for SKK
dbskkd-cdb-2.00nb1 2.00nb1 SKK dictionary server based on cdb
libchewing-0.2.7 0.2.7 The intelligent phonetic input method library
skk-jisyo-201212 201212 Dictionary collection for SKK
autoconf-2.69nb2 2.69nb2 Generates automatic source code configuration scripts
pkg-config-0.28 0.28 System for managing library compile/link flags
python27-2.7.5 2.7.5 Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language`

Comment: @rayray84: and it isn't what you want? Next time write a more clear question.

Comment: Sorry Casimir, thanks for your input though! I was able to get what I needed with Ed answer